# find the value of $x^{(x^{2})}+x^{(x^{8})}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $$x^{(x^{4})}=4$$ Then find the value of $$x^{(x^{2})}+x^{(x^{8})}$$

I did solve this, I want to see more solutions, thanks

Comment: Would you post your solution?

Answer (score 1):

Make a guess for $x$.   We get that $x=\sqrt{2}$ $$x^{2}=2 \qquad \Rightarrow x^{4}=4 \qquad \Rightarrow  x^{8}=16$$

$$\Rightarrow x^{(x^{2})}+x^{(x^{8})}= 2+256=258$$

you can also solve it with using $log$ but it would be a long solution.

and we're done

> Another solution with using $log$:

Let $$y=x^4 \Rightarrow x=y^{\frac{1}{4}}$$
$$x^{x^{4}}=(y^{\frac{1}{4}})^{y}=y^{\frac{y}{4}}$$ $$\Rightarrow \frac{y}{4} log_{4} y =log_{4} 4=1$$ $$\Rightarrow y  log_{4} y=4 \Rightarrow log_{4} y^{y}=4$$ $$4^{log_{4} y^{y}}=4^{4} \Rightarrow y^{y}=4^{4} \Rightarrow y=4$$

$$x^{2}=y^\frac{1}{2}=2$$ $$\Rightarrow x^{8}=y^{2}=16$$ 
Therefore
$$ x^{x^{2}}+x^{x^{8}}=(y^{\frac{1}{4}})^{y^{\frac{1}{2}}}+(y^{\frac{1}{4}})^{y^{2}}$$
$$\Rightarrow y^{\frac{y^{\frac{1}{2}}}{4}}+=y^{\frac{y^{2}}{4}}$$

Hence the result $$4^{\frac{2}{4}}+4^{\frac{16}{4}}=2+256=8$$

**AND WE'RE DONE**

Comment: One addendum to note is that since $\ln x$ and $x^4$ are positive & increasing for $x > 1$, so is $x^4 \ln x$, and therefore also $x^{x^4}$. Therefore $x = \sqrt{2}$ is the only solution for $x$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair see the new solution

Comment: You mean Aleksandar's? Yes, I have been caught by just assuming that no negative solution exists. Should have looked closer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The solutions to that equation are $x= +\sqrt 2$ and $x=-\sqrt 2$.

$\sqrt 2^{2}+\sqrt 2^{16}=2+2^8=258$

This works for plus and minus.

Comment: I would highly suggest showing how derived those solutions.

Comment: @Dr.MV Trial and error.